# AWS Load Balancer - PathCondition case Sensitive

Tags: amazon-web-services, case-sensitive

Dears,
in AWS LoadBalancer the load balancer the Path conditions is case sensitive

[AWS DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html)

We have long list of application that users can write as they want in the web-browser.

```
STACKOverflow.IT go to yy
STACKOverflow.it go to yy
StackOverflow.It go to yy
```

```
STACKOverflow.US go to zz
STACKOverflow.Us go to zz
```

is there a way to testh the Path as case insensitive ? (i.e. applying a tolower function) ?

Thank you

We though about regular expression, but as I now, is not admitted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that on the load balancer natively.

The 2 options I see are :

- Configure the Load Balancer to only catch lower-case paths, and add a Cloudfront in front of it, with a Lambda@Edge that will run for every query, and change the query path to a lower case. You'll need to point your DNS to Cloudfront though.

Or

- Do not do a path based routing in the ALB, but make it forward request to your own reverse proxy, which you can be configured with your own routing rules. This is less ideal as you'll have to maintain that reverse proxy

Cheers